# angularjs dynamic static short urls

Tags: url, angularjs, routes

I have a node.js server with express.

is it possible via routing to get short like:

http://myurl.com/kdkw8

where "kdkw8" is a key from the database (generated random).
youtube has as well such links.
I tried via `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` with no success

is it possible via express redirect or routing `$routeProvider` ?
I tried to match it with regexp:

```
/*routing*/
$routeProvider.when('/*key', { templateUrl: 'partials/blank.html', controller: 'VoteCtrl'});


/*controller */
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('VoteCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$route', '$routeParams', '$compile', function ($scope,$http,$route,$routeParams,$compile) {
    $route.current.templateUrl = 'partials/vote.html';
    $scope.key = $routeParams.key 

    $http.get($route.current.templateUrl).then(function (msg) {
        $('#views').html($compile(msg.data)($scope));
    });
}])
```

any ideas for short urls?

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

if you change

```
when('/*key', ...)
```

to

```
when('/:key', ...)
```

you will get the key in $routeParams.key as indented. Hope this helps, if not, tell us

Comment: no, the url will be myurl.com/kdkw8. I tested it locally, it did work, so it should work for you

Comment: yeah, thanks, so far so good, do you have an idea about server redirection? with express?